# OpenGL Pass texture to next rendering

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am very new to OpenGL, and I am trying to create a 2 pass shader.  Basically, it has two frame buffers and two shader programs.  It runs the first pass as usual, and then I need to take the resulting texture and pass it as an input to the second shader.  How is this done? I cannot seem to see how you take a resulting texture and use it as an input to the next texture?

Here is some code: This code assumes I have setup the second filter program, and some attributes and uniforms in the program correctly

```
@Override
public void onDraw(final int textureId, final FloatBuffer cubeBuffer,final FloatBuffer textureBuffer){
    //this draws the first pass (this is tested and working)
    super.onDraw(textureId, cubeBuffer, textureBuffer);


    //change the program
    GLES20.glUseProgram(secondFilterProgram);

    //clear the old colors
    GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);



    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE3); //change the texture
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, secondFilterOutputTexture[0]);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(secondFilterInputTextureUniform, 3);


    cubeBuffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(secondFilterPositionAttribute, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, cubeBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(secondFilterPositionAttribute);

    textureBuffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(secondFilterTextureCoordinateAttribute, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, textureBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(secondFilterTextureCoordinateAttribute); //same as line from init

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(secondFilterPositionAttribute);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(secondFilterTextureCoordinateAttribute);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

}
```

I feel like I am missing a piece of the puzzle here.  Again, I am very new to OpenGL, so any help, even conceptually is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is called **Render to Texture**

A small tutorial how to do this with android can be found here:
http://blog.shayanjaved.com/2011/05/13/android-opengl-es-2-0-render-to-texture/